# What does it mean to multiply a matrix by $\bmod{p}$

Tags: matrices

I am reading a research paper and in one step they have done $S = B \pmod{19}$ where $S$ and $B$ are both matrices. What does it mean? How do I calculate this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, concerning the title, you're not multiplying.

The meaning of "modulo $p$" is somewhat ambiguous, that is, it is used in two different senses.

It may indicate a binary relation. As noted by @lkat, this is the relation on the integers given by
$$
a \equiv b \pmod{p} \qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad p \mid a - b.
$$
This is actually an equivalence relation.

However, you will find fairly often the symbol $r = a \pmod{p}$ to mean that $r$ is the remainder of Euclidean division of $b$ by $p \ne 0$, that is, $r$ is uniquely determined by
$$
\begin{cases}
a = q p + r\\
0 \le r < \lvert p \rvert
\end{cases}
$$
for some $q$. In fact one always has for this $r$ that $r \equiv a \pmod{p}$, but in general there are many $b$ such that $b \equiv a \pmod{p}$, namely all $b$ of the form $a + t p$, for $t \in \mathbf{Z}$.

Anyway, I assume you were given an integer matrix $B = [b_{ij}]$, and required to compute a matrix $S = [s_{ij}]$, such that $s_{ij} = b_{ij} \pmod{b}$ is the remainder of the division of $b_{ij}$ by $p$, for all $i, j$.

For instance, for
$$
B =\begin{bmatrix}
3&-2\\
6&-7
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
you will have **for $p = 2$ (sorry, I had forgotten to mention that)**
$$
S = \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: In your illustration, what is the value of `b` in `mod b`

Comment: are you saying taht I must simply divide each element of Matrix B by p and put the remainder in the place ?

Comment: @RitwikG Not necessarily; $a\equiv b\bmod p$ might not be a "calculation" as much as could be a generic *statement*. For matrices, $A\equiv B\bmod p$ would state that for each $i,j$, the difference $a_{ij}-b_{ij}$ is a multiple of $p$. This is useful since if $A\equiv B$ and $C\equiv D$, then $A+C\equiv B+D$ and $AC\equiv BD$ (in abstract terms, this says the quotient map $Z\to Z/pZ$ is a ring homomorphism, but this is perhaps too much language to digest at first).

Comment: @RitwikG, sorry, I meant $p = 2$.

Comment: @RitwikG, and yes, replace the elements of $B$ with their remainders.

Answer (score 2):

Given two integers $a$, $b$, we have the equivalence $a\equiv b$ (mod $p$) if $a-b$ is divisible by $p$ (usually $p$ will be a prime number). In terms of matrices, $A\equiv B$ (mod $p$) means that $a_{ij}\equiv b_{ij}$ (mod $p$) for every entry in $A$ and $B$.

Edit: To compute an integer mod $p$, you may successively subtract $p$ and compute its remainder. e.g. $21\equiv 16\equiv 11\equiv 6\equiv 1$ (mod $5$).

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your illustration. Are you saying that if I want to calculate 21(mod 5), I must subtract 5 from 21 five times ? Is `21(mod 5) = 1` ? Similarly is `48 (mod 2) =44` ?